# strange property result for picture path of the current user in applescript

Tags: applescript, system-preferences, dscl

When I run:

```
tell application "System Events"
   get the properties of the current user
end tell
```

in applescript, everything looks fine except for the picture path. The path referenced is not what I see as my user picture.

I am probably missing something here, but I do not know what. Does the picture in the path referenced serve another purpose than the picture that I set to be my User Picture in System Preferences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short
account image is 'JPEGPhoto' attribute of user record and `get the properties of the current user` is returning 'Picture' attribute of user record.

Mac OS X 10.5+ stores user's account pictures within the Directory Service. User account contains a 'Picture'(that is a path to the account pictures) and 'JPEGPhoto' attribute in their user record .This can be read using the `dscl` command (`dscl . -read /Users/username Picture` and `dscl . -read /Users/username JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p >  /accountImage.jpg`).(initially  both are same)

If a user has modified their user picture at any time using `system preferences` the account picture  is stored in the '`JPEGPhoto`' attribute of their user record not in '`Picture`' attribute.

If a user has modified their user picture at any time using `applescript` the account picture  is stored in the '`Picture`' attribute of their user record not in '`JPEGPhoto`' attribute.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the picture path of current user to "/Library/User Pictures/Flowers/Dahlia.tif"
end tell
```

Your `applescript` is returning '`Picture`' attribute of user record.

**Reference:**
[Where does the Mac store account pictures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/where-does-the-mac-store-account-pictures)

Comment: IN Mac OS X version 10.7.4 DirectoryService has been replaced by opendirectoryd(8).

Comment: I'm running 10.7.4 and the second dscl command returned my user picture. The first one returned the same as the system events command which is wrong.

Comment: account image is 'JPEGPhoto' attribute of user record.